# How to add Google Maps marker underneath existing markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

When I search my map it adds a pin, but it covers the original marker making it impossible for the user to click (eg if you search for '*Cheltenham*' on [my map](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZBreY)).

Is there a way to add the search marker beneath existing markers?

I've tried playing round with `zIndex` but couldn't get it to work.

Codepen of map here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZBreY

Any ideas?

Comment: What did you try with zIndex?

Comment: I tried adding zIndex to:
markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            icon: icon,
                            title: place.name,
                            position: place.geometry.location,
                            zIndex: 999999
                          }));

Comment: To be honest I've tried adding it to a lots of different places and changing the values but none of them have worked. I'm not really sure where I should be adding it.

Comment: Did you add it to _all_ the markers?

Comment: Does your [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZBreY) do anything useful? I get a javascript error: `Uncaught InvalidValueError: initAutocomplete is not a function`

Comment: You probably should include the fact that your markers come from a FusionTablesLayer in your question.

Comment: I fixed the codepen. I'd like the pin that appears when you search for location, to be placed behind existing markers so that it doesn't get in the way.

Answer (score 0):

1. One option would be to query the FusionTable and render the markers as native Google Maps Javascript API v3 markers, then zIndex will work.

Looking at your FusionTable, it doesn't contain coordinates, so that won't be possible unless you update it.

2. Another option would be to make the marker a transparent circle that doesn't obscure the markers:

[concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/sr9v9jt4/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initAutocomplete() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.53081624504545, -3.0102),
    zoom: 6,
    // maxZoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });


  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend-open'));
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend'));

  layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    map: map,
    heatmap: {
      enabled: false
    },
    query: {
      select: "col3",
      from: "1HYIx5EfvhdMJY_oQAedrrbzONPviYJocD0DMz53V",
      where: "col9 \x3d \x27YES\x27"
    },
    options: {
      styleId: 3,
      templateId: 2
    }
  });

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });
  var markers = [];
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];
    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      var icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };
      // Create a marker for each place.
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: {
          path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
          scale: 10,
          fillColor: "#00FF00",
          fillOpacity: 0.4,
          strokeWeight: 1,
          strokeOpacity: 0.4,
          strokeColor: "#00FF00",
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
        }, //icon,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      }));
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: {
          path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
          scale: 3,
          fillColor: "#0000FF",
          fillOpacity: 0.4,
          strokeWeight: 1,
          strokeOpacity: 0.4,
          strokeColor: "#0000FF",
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
        }, //icon,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      }));

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initAutocomplete);
```

```css
 html,
 body {
   height: 500px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
 #map {
   height: 500px;
   max-width: 100%;
 }
 .controls {
   margin-top: 10px;
   border: 1px solid transparent;
   border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   height: 32px;
   outline: none;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 }
 #pac-input {
   background-color: #fff;
   font-family: Roboto;
   font-size: 15px;
   font-weight: 300;
   margin-left: 12px;
   padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   width: 300px;
 }
 #pac-input:focus {
   border-color: #4d90fe;
 }
 .pac-container {
   font-family: Roboto;
 }
 #type-selector {
   color: #fff;
   background-color: #4d90fe;
   padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
 }
 #type-selector label {
   font-family: Roboto;
   font-size: 13px;
   font-weight: 300;
 }
 #target {
   width: 345px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search for a screening near you">
<div id="map"></div>
```